# Apple iOS 17.2 Simulator keeps appearing in Disk Utility. Doesn't go away

Tags: disk-utility, sonoma, xcode-simulator

I am running MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1. Whenever I boot or reboot, a strange disk image keeps showing up in disk utility. If I eject it, they go away until I reboot. After every reboot, they reappear. The disk image in question contains iOS 17.2.21C62 Simulator. I believe when opening xcode for the first time, it asked me if I wanted to install an iOS simulator, but that is all I know about this disk image.

[image: Apple Disk Utility with iOS Simulator showing up as a disk image]

Why does this disk image keep appearing in Disk utiliy, and how do I get rid of it?
See picture below for details.

Answer (score 2):

That is the iOS Simulator runtime that you or someone else installed in order to do iOS development on the system.  You can delete it from Xcode's preferences if you don't need to do iOS development.

The other is related to Time Machine, if you disable that (temporarily) and restart the Mac, it should not appear. Then you can know that recent disk image only arrives when you have Time Machine running.